# Is it possible to sort on labels?

Tags: sorting, nosql, neo4j, graph-databases

Is it possible to specify the sorting for a label allowing nodes with this label to be efficiently retrieved in the specified sort-order?

Comment: You mean something like:

MATCH (n:A:B)
RETURN n
ORDER by labels(n) or ORDER by labels(n)[0]

Comment: I rather mean if it's possible to define the sorting - e.g. ascending or descending, for the values of a label so that when you retrieve them they are fetched in that order at core level

Comment: Not right now but that's a good idea. You certainly mean values of a property?

Comment: Do you have a concrete use-case for this? I'm curious.

Comment: Yeah for example a property holding a date/time value. In that case having the ability to specify the order in which it's indexed, queries such as "give me the X most recent nodes" would be almost immediate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not; see Michael Hunger [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403009/is-it-possible-to-sort-on-labels#comment32287239_21403009)

The Neo4j docs that I could find on this are a bit sparse:

- [Neo4j docs - User database with indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html)

You can see there that people in the comments are [asking](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html#comment-1074710039) for exactly this feature.